# WPF - When application Loads, do not steal Focus from any another application

Tags: wpf, focus

I have a simple WPF application. When it loads and I am typing in any other application (like Word or IM), my WPF app steals the focus - screwing up my typing, of course. Now, this is the very behavior I find annoying in other applications. How can I prevent this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question. I've found this which is good to read. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `ShowActivated = false` on your window prior to calling `Show()` should accomplish what you want.